# Android: Cannot show more than one image

Tags: android, uiimage, image-manipulation

I have the following main class and thread-TCP Client. The client runs in a loop, receives messages and passes it to main class. In the main class, I parse the message and try to show different images based on the name and value of the message received.
Ex: shiftDirection1
name: shiftDirection & value: 1

But I can show only the image corresponding to the first received message and the images corresponding to the remaining received messages cannot be displayed.

Please go through the code below and kindly suggest the mistake/problem and alternative ways.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Madhu

main class:

```
public class TCPListen extends Activity implements TCPListener {
    private TextView mTitle;
    public String recData[] = new String[2];
    String PresentGear = "0";   

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override  
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 

             TcpServiceHandler handler = new TcpServiceHandler(this,this);  
             Thread th = new Thread(handler);  
             th.start();      
         }          

         public String[] callCompleted(String source){ 
                //Log.d("TCP", "Std parser " + source);
                //mTitle.setText(source);
                //String data[] = new String[2]; 

                //if (source.matches("<MSG><N>.*</N><V>.*</V></MSG>"))  {           
                    Document doc = null;  
                    try{
                       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
                       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();  
                       doc = (Document) db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes()));  
                       NodeList n = doc.getElementsByTagName("N");  
                       Node nd = n.item(0);  
                       String msgName = nd.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();  
                       NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("V");  
                       Node nd1 = n1.item(0);  
                       String tmpVal = nd1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();  
                       recData[0] = msgName;  
                       recData[1] = tmpVal;
                       if (recData[0].equals("currGear"))   PresentGear = recData[1];
                       Log.d("TCP", "Inside Std parser " + recData[0] + " " + recData[1]);
                       actionOnData(recData[0], recData[1]);
                      }  
                    catch(Exception e){  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }                   
                Log.d("TCP", "Just outside Std parser " + recData[0] + " " + recData[1]);
                return recData;
                //} else Log.d("TCP", "Message in wrong format " + source);
                //mTitle.setText("Message in wrong format " + source);
                //return data;
            }


       //Function to display driver messages/images based on individual messages
         public void actionOnData(String name, String value) {
            String tempName = name;
            String tempVal = value; 
            setContentView(R.layout.image);
            ImageView showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            //Log.d("TCP", "------------>" + tempName + "  " + tempVal);            

            if (tempName.equals("shiftDirection") && tempVal.equals("1")) {
                //setContentView(R.layout.image);
                //TextView text_top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);            
                //text_bottom.setText(Info[1]);
                showImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shift_up);
                Log.d("TCP", "1------------>" + showImage);
             } else if (tempName.equals("shiftDirection") && tempVal.equals("-1")) {                 
                //setContentView(R.layout.image);
                //TextView text_bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                //Resources res = getResources();
                //Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.shift_down);

                //showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);            
                //text_bottom.setText(Info[1]);
                showImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shift_down);              
             } else if (tempName.equals("recomGear") && tempVal != null) {
                 Log.d("TCP", "3------------>" + tempName + "  " + tempVal);
                Integer msgValue = Integer.parseInt(recData[1]);
                //Integer CurrentGear = (msgValue) - 1;
                //Log.d("TCP","in DA Images. Current gear: " + CurrentGear);
                //String Gear = Integer.toString(CurrentGear);
                setContentView(R.layout.image);
                TextView text_top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView text_bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
                showImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shift_up);
                text_bottom.setText(PresentGear);
                text_top.setText(tempVal);
             } else if (tempName.equals("currGear") && tempVal != null) {
                 Log.d("TCP", "4------------>" + tempName + "  " + tempVal);
                PresentGear = tempVal;          
                //Log.d("TCP","in DA Images. Present gear1: " + PresentGear);
                setContentView(R.layout.image);
                TextView text_bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                text_bottom.setText(PresentGear);                       
             } else if (tempName.equals("shiftDirection") && tempVal.equals("0")) {
                 Log.d("TCP", "5------------>" + tempName + "  " + tempVal);
                Log.d("TCP","in DA Images. Present gear: " + PresentGear);
                setContentView(R.layout.image);
                TextView text_bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                //TextView text_top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //text_top.setText("Go on");  
                text_bottom.setText(PresentGear);           
             }          
          }
}
```

Only the image corresponding to the first if case is displayed. The program control enters the second if loop but does not show the image there.

Interface:

```
public interface TCPListener {
    public String[] callCompleted(String msg);
}
```

Thread (TCP Client):

```
public class TcpServiceHandler implements Runnable {  
     TCPListener _listener;            
     private Activity _act; 
     public BufferedReader in;
     public TcpServiceHandler(TCPListener listener, Activity act){    
         _listener = listener;  
         _act = act;  
     }        

     public synchronized void run() {  
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
         //if(socket==null){    
             try {  
                 //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.178.25");  
                 Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.62.23", 1200, true);  
         //  
                 //while(true){  
                  try {                           
                         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));  
                         final int delay = 100;
                         final Timer _timer = new Timer();
                         _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {                       
                            public void run(){
                                String str;
                                try {
                                    str = in.readLine();
                                    _listener.callCompleted(str);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                         }, 0, delay); 
                         //final String str = in.readLine();  
                         //this._act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){  

                         //public void run() {  
                        //   _listener.callCompleted(str);  
                           //  }                                
                         //});                                                  
                  }  
                  catch(Exception e){  
                      e.printStackTrace();  
                  }  
                 //}  
             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {  
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             } catch (IOException e) {  
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             }  
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might check 2 things:

1. Your `TcpServiceHandler` is a `Runnable` of a thread but there is no loop in `run()`. The _timer you define inside this method might be dead and gone before it's work is done.
2. Are you changing the UI from a background thread? This is not a good idea in general.
3. Check `AsyncTask` which is a handy tool to run operations in the background.

Comment: The timer inside TcpServiceHandler is working properly. In fact, all incoming messages are passed to the main class as well. But the images do not get displayed. I think I am not changing the UI from background thread. I have tried the async task earlier but it complicated things for me.

Comment: Your updates are running in the timer thread. AsyncTask is designed to pass things between something that happens in the background and UI updates that must happen in the main thread. IMHO this is exactly what you need. You can implement your own Handler or call runOnUiThread() (I guess that is what you tried in the commented-out code) but then again you are just reimplementing AsyncTask.